# 4th order differential equation from Euler-Lagrange

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to extremise the functional $\int{[y + \frac{1}{2}y^2 - \frac{1}{2}(y^{''})^2]}dy$ and so from Euler-Lagrange I get the differential equation

$1 + y + y^{(4)} = 0$ and I have no idea how to solve it. It's supposed to be an easy question so there must be a trick.

I have the initial conditions $y(0) = -1, y'(0) = 0, y(\pi) = \cosh(\pi), y'(\pi) = \sinh(\pi)$.

Just to check, I'm using the E-L equation, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{''}} = 0$

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: Your functional has no explicit $x$-dependence, so were it not for the $y''$-dependence you could simply appeal to the Beltrami identity ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_identity)). That obviously won't work directly here, but the derivation of said identity in the Wikipeda link can perhaps be adapted to the case at hand.

Comment: You got a sign wrong, it seems. The E-L equation becomes $1+y-y^{(4)}=0$ instead.

Comment: Just in case you are interested, your equation is related to Bernoulli-Euler beam equation, which is a classical way to describe the bending of beams at small frequencies.

Comment: I was too lazy to figure out whether or not my comment above was actually valid, so I posted a question re: generalizing the Beltrami identity [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773305/137524).

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have some background. This is a past exam question for my course, so I don't get any context for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your equation should be $1+y-y^{(4)}=0$, but in any case it's a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, so you get the particular solution $y_p(x)=-1$ and solve the homogeneous differential equation
$$y_h^{(4)}-y_h=0$$
The trial function is $y=e^{rx}$ leading to the characteristic equation $r^4-1=(r+1)(r-1)(r+i)(r-i)=0$, so the general solution is
$$y(x)=-1+c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x+c_3\cosh x+c_4\sinh x$$
Applying initial conditions, $y(0)=-1=-1+c_1+c_3$, $y^{\prime}(0)=0=c_2+c_4$, $y(\pi)=\cosh(\pi)=-1-c_1+c_3\cosh\pi+c_4\sinh\pi$, $y^{\prime}(\pi)=\sinh\pi=-c_2+c_3\sinh\pi+c_4\cosh\pi$, we should be able to get a solution.

**EDIT** The solution turns out to be very simple, as might have been expected from the initial conditions: $c_3=1=-c_1$, $c_4=0=-c_2$.