# What is the shape of the perfect coffee cup for heat retention assuming coffee is being drunk at a constant rate?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, 3d, maxima-minima

[image: diagram]

Find the optimal shape of a coffee cup for heat retention. Assuming

1. A constant coffee flow rate out of the cup.
2. All surfaces radiate heat equally, i.e. liquid surface, bottom of cup and sides of cup.
3. The coffee is drunk quickly enough that the temperature differential between the coffee and the environment can be ignored/assumed constant.

So we just need to minimise the average surface area as the liquid drains

I have worked out the following 2 alternative equations for the average surface area over the lifetime of the liquid in the cup (see below for derivations):

$$ S_{ave} =\pi r_0^2+ \frac{\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}{{r(s)}^4ds}+\frac{2\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}{\int_{0}^{s}{r\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{dz}\right)^2}\ dz\ }{r(s)}^2ds\ } \tag{1}$$

$$S_{ave}=\pi r_0^2+\frac{\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}r\left(s\right)^4ds+\frac{2\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}r(s){\underbrace{\int_{s}^{h}{{r\left(z\right)}^2dz\ }}_{\text{Volume Drunk}}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2}ds \tag{2}$$

If the volume of the cup is constant

$$ V=\pi\int_{0}^{h}{{r(z)}^2dz\ }$$

Can the function,  $r(z)$, be found that minimises the average surface area $S_{ave}$?

If r is expressed as a parametric equation in the form $r=f(t), z=g(t)$ and $f,g$ are polynomials then a genetic search found the best function of parametric polynomials to be: $r\left(z\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}z^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt6}{9}z^\frac{3}{2}, f\left(t\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}t-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}t^3, g\left(t\right)=\frac{9}{2}t^2$

This parametric shape has a maximum radius of 1, height of 4.5, starting volume of $\frac{3^4}{2^5}\pi$ and is shown here:
[image: Best Parametric Polynomials]

I can't prove that there is (or is not) a better $r(z)$ but...

the average surface area of this surface turns out to be $12.723452r^2$ or $4.05\pi r_{max}^2$.
I suspect that the optimal surface will have the same surface area as a sphere, i.e. $4\pi r_{max}^2$ $(12.5664)$

**Conjecture: The optimally shaped coffee cup has the same average surface area as a sphere of the same maximum radius.** Shown to be false by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4704272/1050333)

**Derivation of Surface Area Formula:**

Surface area when surface of liquid is at level s is the sum of the areas of the top disc, bottom disc and the sides.

$S(s)=\pi r_0^2+\pi r_s^2+2\pi\int_{0}^{s}{r(z)dldz}$

$S(s)=\pi r_0^2+\pi r_s^2+2\pi\int_{0}^{s}{r(z)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{dz}\right)^2}\ dz\ }$

The average surface area will be the sum of all the As’s times the time spent at each surface area.

$S_{ave}=\frac{1}{T}\int_{t_0}^{t_h}{S(s)dt\ }$

In order to have the drain rate constant we need to set the flow rate Q to be constant i.e. the rate of change volume is constant and $Q=dV/dt =V/T$

Time spent at a particular liquid level $dt\ =\frac{T}{V}dV$ and $
dV={\pi r}^2ds$

$dt=\frac{T\pi r^2}{V}ds$

$S_{ave}=\int_{s=0}^{s=h}{S(s)\frac{T\pi{r(s)}^2}{V}ds\ }$
$S_{ave}=\frac{\pi}{V}\int_{s=0}^{s=h}{(r_0^2+r(s)^2+2\int_{z=0}^{z=s}{r(z)\sqrt{1+(\frac{dr(z)}{dz})^2}\ dz\ })\pi{r(s)}^2ds\ }$

$S_{ave}=\frac{\pi}{V}r_0^2\int_{0}^{h}{\pi{r(s)}^2ds}+\frac{\pi}{V}\int_{s=0}^{s=h}{\left(r\left(s\right)^2+2\int_{z=0}^{z=s}{r(z)\sqrt{1+(\frac{dr(z)}{dz})^2}\ dz\ }\right)\pi{r(s)}^2ds\ }$

$S_{ave}=\pi\ r_0^2+\frac{\pi^2}{V}\int_{s=0}^{s=h}{\left(r\left(s\right)^2+2\int_{z=0}^{z=s}{r(z)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr(z)}{dz}\right)^2}\ dz\ }\right){r(s)}^2ds\ }$

**Alternative Formula Derivation:**

Surface area of highlighted ribbon in the diagram is:

$S_{ribbon}=2\pi rdl$

And the contribution towards the average surface area lasts for the ratio of volume of the liquid above the current level to the total volume.

$$S_{sides}=2\pi\frac{\pi}{V}{\underbrace{\int_{s}^{h}{{r\left(z\right)}^2dz\ }}_{\text{Volume Drunk}}}rdl=\frac{2\pi^2}{V}{\underbrace{\int_{s}^{h}{{r\left(z\right)}^2dz\ }}_{\text{Volume Drunk}}}r\left(s\right)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2}ds$$

Integrate the contribution of all such sections.

$$S_{sides}=\frac{2\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}{r\left(s\right){\underbrace{\int_{s}^{h}{{r\left(z\right)}^2dz\ }}_{\text{Volume Drunk}}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2}ds}$$

Contribution of top surfaces to average surface area is area of top by proportion of volume that area x dz is:

$$S_{tops}=\frac{1}{V}\int_{0}^{h}{\pi{r(s)}^2{\pi r(s)}^2}ds$$

Contribution of bottom surface is constant $\pi r_0^2$ so adding together all three gives:

$$S_{ave}=\pi r_0^2+\frac{\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}r\left(s\right)^4ds+\frac{2\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}r(s){\underbrace{\int_{s}^{h}{{r\left(z\right)}^2dz\ }}_{\text{Volume Drunk}}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2}ds$$

---

Comment: If there was a coffee tag, I think this question would immediately receive much stronger attention

Comment: Question: are you asking about the coffee radiating heat from the surface in contact with the air or the coffee in contact with the side of the coffee mug?

Comment: Would you accept a solution in the form of an integro-differential equation? That double integral in the surface area is going to generate an integral term in the variational equations for the optimum shape, which makes it highly unlikely that you'll get a closed-form solution for the shape.

Comment: @aghostinthefigures: If the integro-differential equation leads to a closed form solution, then of course.

Comment: @QC_QAOA. All surfaces, top, sides and bottom. I have clarified this in the assumptions in the question.

Comment: $\int 2 \pi r ds + \pi r^2 $ is to be minimised for constant $ \int \pi r^2 dz$?

Comment: @Narasimham. Yes, I think so, if you ignore the bottom disc, which is probably zero area.

Comment: Yes, the bottom disc has constant area so disappears in a variational calculus approach.

Comment: Okay, I have a better understanding of the question now. Quick notes, the units check out which is good. Should the limits for Volume Drunk be $s\to h$ and not $h\to s$ since that makes a negative volume, leading to a negative surface area contribution

Comment: @QC_QAOA. I think it is $h->s$ because $h>s$ and the volume decreases from h to s.

Comment: $P'=r^2$ gives the equivalent problem $$\min\int_0^hP'^2+\left(P-\frac V\pi\right)\sqrt{4P'+P''^2}\,ds$$ where $V=\pi P(h)$. Euler-Lagrange gives $$\frac{4(P-V/\pi)(2+P''')+P''(4P'+P''^2)}{(4P'+P''^2)^{3/2}}=1+\frac C{P'^2}$$ where $C$ is a constant.

Comment: @MichaelMcL1960 I'd suggest you post this on MathOverflow if there's no answers in the next few days. (if you do, please make sure to add a link this MSE post to let readers know you've crossposted)

Comment: Why are you minimizing the surface area using $r_{max}$ rather than the volume? I feel like volume would make more sense in the context of this problem.

Comment: Isn’t $h>s$? Should the bounds in your integral be reversed?

Comment: @Eric, you could be right. That is what QC said, otherwise there is a negative volume, but it starts with the higher volume $h$ and it drops to $s$ so I'm not sure. I'll think about it.

Comment: @QC_QAOA, Eric I reversed the integral limits in the second formula.

Comment: @VarunVejalla. Yes, I would be very interested in seeing it that way too. Any chance I could persuade you to take up the gauntlet?

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447083/what-is-the-shape-of-the-perfect-coffee-cup-for-heat-retention-assuming-coffee-i

Comment: @TheSimpliFire . As Gerry Myerson says, I took your advice and cross posted this on Mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447083/what-is-the-shape-of-the-perfect-coffee-cup-for-heat-retention-assuming-coffee-i. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have labelled the two equations for the average surface area. @TheSimpliFire, when you worked out the differential equations did you start from eqn(1) or eqn(2)?

Comment: @MichaelMcL1960 I started with equation (2), however, I worked out the version with the earlier $\int_h^s$ not $\int_s^h$ so my differential equation is wrong due to sign errors. I will post an answer with the new version and some more steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

For a coffee cup of volume $\frac{81\pi}{32}$ the shape of maximum heat retention is the surface of revolution of $$r(z)=\sqrt\frac{3}{2}z^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{9}z^{\frac{3}{2}}$$.

The height of this cup is $4.5$ and the max radius is $1$. For other starting volumes, V, the radius and height scale by $(\frac{32V}{81\pi})^\frac{1}{3}.$

**Proof:**

In the question I show that the average surface area for a coffee cup is:

$$S_{ave}=\pi r_0^2+\frac{\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}r\left(s\right)^4ds+\frac{2\pi^2}{V}\int_{0}^{h}r(s){\underbrace{\int_{s}^{h}{{r\left(z\right)}^2dz\ }}_{\text{Volume Drunk}}}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dr}{ds}\right)^2}ds \tag{2}$$ and ask what function of $r$ minimises this. Recall that I give $(1)$ as the best equation I have found using a genetic search algorithm.

TheSimpliFire showed in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703322/1050333) and Varun Vejalla show in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4702324/1050333) (with a scaling of $\pi$ difference) that the optimal shape must be a solution to the third-order ODE:
$$\frac{4(P(h)-P)(2+P''')-P''(4P'+P''^2)}{(4P'+P''^2)^{3/2}}=1+\frac C{P'^2}\tag{3}$$

where $P'=r^2(z)$

Let's plug $(1)$ into $(3)$ and see if it is a solution.

Using $P=\frac{3\ z^2}{4}-\frac{2\ z^3}{9}+\frac{z^4}{54}+K$ (Where $K$ is the constant of integration).

The numerator of the LHS evaluates to:
$$\frac{81}{4}-8\left(\frac{3\ z^2}{4}-\frac{2\ z^3}{9}+\frac{z^4}{54}\right)+4\left(\frac{81}{32}-\left(\frac{3\ z^2}{4}-\frac{2\ z^3}{9}+\frac{z^4}{54}\right)\right)\left(\frac{4\ z}{9}-\frac{4}{3}\right)-4\left(\frac{3\ z}{2}\ -\frac{2\ z^2}{3}\ +\frac{2\ z^3}{27}\right)\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{4\ z}{3}+\frac{2\ z^2}{9}\right)-\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{4\ z}{3}+\frac{2\ z^2}{9}\right)^3$$

$$=\frac{27}{8}+\frac{9z}{2}+\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{28z^3}{27}-\frac{2z^4}{27}+\frac{8z^5}{81}-\frac{8z^6}{729}$$

$$=-\frac{(-27-12z+4z^2)^3}{5832}$$

The denominator is:

$$\left(4\left(\frac{3\ z}{2}\ -\frac{2\ z^2}{3}\ +\frac{2\ z^3}{27}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{4\ z}{3}+\frac{2\ z^2}{9}\right)^2\right)\frac{3}{2}$$

$$=\frac{\left(\left(-27\ -\ 12\ z\ +\ 4\ z^2\right)^6\right)^\frac{1}{2}}{5832}$$

Which is always equal to either the numerator or its negative

$$\frac{-(-27-12z+4z^2)^3}{\sqrt{(27 + 12 z - 4 z^2)^6}} = \pm1\tag{4}$$
But $P'=r^2 \implies r=\pm \sqrt {P'}$

So we can rewrite the ODE as
$$\frac{4(P(h)-P)(2+P''')-P''(4P'+P''^2)}{\pm(4P'+P''^2)^{3/2}}=1+\frac C{P'^2}\tag{3a}$$

squaring both sides of (3a) and (4), we see that $(1)$ satisfies the ODE with $C=0$

Q.E.D.

Well, almost. The function is at a stationary point. Any small change in the coefficients increases the surface area so it’s not a maximum, so it must be a minimum. Now I just need to see if it is also a global minimum.

Comment: This looks to only be true for $h=4.5$, but $h$ is also a variable that can be chosen as long as $P(h)$ is a fixed value, so I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. This is the shape when the max radius is $1$, $\implies V=81\pi/32, h=4.5$. For other volumes the max radius and height scales by $V^\frac{1}{3}$. Perhaps I should generalise it somehow?

Comment: @MichaelMcL1960 We need to test whether it is a global minimum instead of a local minimum (as that gives the chance for another function to have an even smaller solution). There are ways to do this, but I'm still surprised the ODE is solved this way. It is very rare to have a solution "by inspection"

Comment: OK @TheSimpliFire. ! could do with some help (again) on that. It wasn't solely by inspection. I had already searched, with a genetic algorithm, for 2 polynomials $z=g(t),r=f(t)$ that gave the smallest surface area and the coefficients kept converging to $g(t)=4.5t^2,f(t)=t−t^3$. I first tried lots of other parametric functions, exponentials, sines/cosine variations, but when I finally tried polynomials they fit much better.
 but I wasn't able to prove it was optimal.

Comment: I really like this tear shaped function. There's no hole in the top, so it wouldn't make a great coffee cup but it is a fundamental shape in that it is THE shape with the minimal average surface area for a given volume of liquid that is draining away. A bit like a sphere in that respect.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, so do I have to show that $L_{p''}^{''}$ is always > $0$?

Comment: Not quite, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations#Variations_and_sufficient_condition_for_a_minimum. I'll try to give a detailed explanation next week when I'm less busy

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, my hunch about the square root was right. Now the whole function satisfies the ODE if you take $r=\pm \sqrt{P'}$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire, now that the moderator strike is over and you are back in the saddle so to speak, do you think you could help to prove that this is also a global minimum? My intuition is that it is and that this shape is an important fundamental shape.

Comment: @MichaelMcLaughlin Sorry I completely forgot about your question. Just prior to the strike I remember trying to prove it was global but the algebra got to a point that was too long for me to continue. I still think it's doable (see my last wikipedia link).

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really a solution - just rewriting it in terms of a fourth-order differential equation. I've also cross-posted this answer on MathOverflow.

---

Let $$V(t):=\pi\int_0^tr(s)^2ds$$

We can then rewrite $r(s)$ as $$r(s)=\sqrt{\frac{V'(s)}{\pi}}$$

If we rewrite $S_{ave}$ using just $V$, we get $$S_{ave}=\pi\sqrt{\frac{V'\left(0\right)}{\pi}}+\frac{\pi^{2}}{V\left(h\right)}\int_{0}^{h}\left(\left(\frac{V'\left(s\right)}{\pi}\right)^{2}+2\sqrt{\frac{V'\left(s\right)}{\pi}}\int_{s}^{h}\frac{V'\left(z\right)}{\pi}dz\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4\pi}\cdot\frac{V''\left(s\right)^{2}}{V'\left(s\right)}}\right)ds$$

The inner integral simplifies to $\frac{1}{\pi}(V(h)-V(s))$, so this simplifies to (getting rid of some of the $\pi$ terms as well) $$\sqrt{\pi V'(0)}+\frac{1}{V(h)}\int_{0}^{h}\left(V'(s)^2+2\cdot(V(h)-V(s))\sqrt{\pi V'(s)+\frac{V''(s)^2}{4}}\right)ds$$

We want to minimize this value assuming a fixed $V(h)$. Assume we have a fixed $V'(0)$ and $h$ as well. We then want to minimize $\frac{\sqrt{\pi V'(0)}}{h}+\frac{1}{V(h)}\mathcal{L}(s,V, V', V'')$, where $\mathcal{L}(s,V, V', V'')$ is given by $$(V')^2+2\cdot(V_h-V)\sqrt{\pi V'+\frac{(V'')^2}{4}}$$

and $V_h=V(h)$. We can then use the [Euler-Lagrange equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation#Single_function_of_single_variable_with_higher_derivatives) to get that the stationary points of the average surface area (with respect to $V(s)$) would be given by $$\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial V}-\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial V'}\right)+\frac{d^2}{ds^2}\left(\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial V''}\right)=0$$

This ends up being a fourth-order differential equation with a long form (I started writing it out before realizing that the last term would make it be very long).

---

Edit: Using the Beltrami identity, which TheSimpliFire mentioned in a comment, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1773488/595055), we can write $$\mathcal{L}-V'\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial V'}+V'\frac{d}{ds}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial V''}-V''\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial V''}=C$$

Plugging in $\mathcal{L}$ and simplifying, we get $$-V'(s)^{2}\left(1+\frac{V''(s)\left(4\pi V'(s)+V''(s)^{2}\right)+4\pi\left(V(s)-V_{h}\right)\left(2\pi+V^{(3)}(s)\right)}{\left(4\pi V'(s)+V''(s)^{2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\right) = C$$

Comment: I have already given this result [in the comments above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692831/what-is-the-shape-of-the-perfect-coffee-cup-for-heat-retention-assuming-coffee-i/4702324#comment9942224_4692831), where I used the substitution $P'=r^2$ instead of $P'=\pi r^2$. (at least, on MathOverflow I think it would be better as a comment - don't need to show all the steps).

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Shoot sorry about that, I should have read the comments more carefully.

Comment: The differential equation is not very long once you simplify (I've edited my comment above to add the simplified form). However, I don't think anybody would expect an analytical family of solutions in closed form, even if $C=0$. For some more details, I reduced the order from $4$ to $3$ as $\cal L$ as independent of $s$ and thus we can derive a "second-order Beltrami identity".

Answer (score 1):

We are interested in minimising $$I(h)=\int_0^hr(s)^4+2r(s)\sqrt{1+r'(s)^2}\int_s^hr(z)^2\,dz\,ds$$ such that $V=\pi\int_0^hr(s)^2\,ds$. The substitution $P'=r^2$ with $P(h)=V/\pi$ means that $r'=P''/2r$ so $$I(h)=\int_0^hP'^2+\sqrt{4P'+P''^2}\left(P(h)-P\right)\,ds.$$ Let $L(P,P',P'')$ denote the integrand. As this is independent of $s$, we can derive the second-order Beltrami identity as follows.

Recall the total derivative $L'=L_s+L_PP'+L_{P'}P''+L_{P''}P'''$ which rearranges to $$L_PP'=L'-L_{P'}P''-L_{P''}P'''$$ as $L_s=0$. The second-order Euler-Lagrange equation is $$L_P-L_{P'}'+L_{P''}''=0\implies L_PP'-L_{P'}'P'+L_{P''}''P'=0.$$ Substituting the first equation gives $L'-L_{P'}P''-L_{P''}P'''-L_{P'}'P'+L_{P''}''P'=0$ which can be rewritten as $(L+(L_{P''}'-L_{P'})P'-L_{P''}P'')'=0$. Thus $$L+(L_{P''}'-L_{P'})P'-L_{P''}P''=C$$ where $C$ is a constant, $$L_{P'}=2P'+\frac{2(P(h)-P)}{\sqrt{4P'+P''^2}},\quad L_{P''}=\frac{P''(P(h)-P)}{\sqrt{4P'+P''^2}}$$ and $$L_{P''}'=\frac{(P(h)-P)(4P'P'''-2P''^2)}{(4P'+P''^2)^{3/2}}-\frac{P'P''}{\sqrt{4P'+P''^2}}.$$ Plugging all of these expressions in and simplifying gives $$\frac{4(P(h)-P)(2+P''')-P''(4P'+P''^2)}{(4P'+P''^2)^{3/2}}=1+\frac C{P'^2}$$ which is now a third-order ODE.

Equivalently, substituting $Q=P(h)-P$ yields $$\frac{4Q}{Q''}R'(Q)+Q''R(Q)=1+\frac C{Q'^2}$$ where $Q''^2-4Q'=R^{-2}$. Differentiating both sides gives $$Q'''=2+\frac{(R^{-2})'}{2Q''}$$ but this is of Abel type with no known closed form solution.

A minor result is that if $r(s)$ is a signomial then $\deg r\ge1$, as the ODE would imply the equality $\max\{2\deg P-3,3\deg P-6\}=\max\{\deg P-1,2\deg P-4\}$ forcing $\deg P\ge3$.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the calculus of variations but I think this is saying that if we find a P that satisfies your 3rd order ODE, we have found a function that minimises that average surface area. Is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelMcL1960 I have added some more details and simplified the ODE. Re your question, not necessarily, Euler-Lagrange guarantees a stationary path but we need further tests to determine whether it is a local/global maximum/minimum. In a similar way to determining the nature of a function's critical point, we need second derivatives.

Comment: I think maybe that when you took P' into the radical you have a small error which has propagated. Shouldn't the term under the radical be $\sqrt{4P'(1+P''^2)}$ ?

Comment: No, $P'=r^2$ means $P''=2rr'=2\sqrt{P'}r'$ so $$2r\sqrt{1+r'^2}=2\sqrt{P'}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{P''}{2\sqrt{P'}}\right)^2}=\sqrt{4P'+P''^2}$$

Comment: Ah. Yes, I see.

Comment: See my answer. Could the jump I see in the LHS of the ODE from 1 to −1 outside the limits of integration be resolved by taking $+/−\sqrt{f(P)}$  in one of the equations that lead to the ODE?

Answer (score -2):

A variational calculus approach.

$\int 2 \pi r ds + \pi r^2 $ is to be minimised for constant $ \int \pi r^2 dz$. In Cartesian coordinates

$$2 \pi\int y \sqrt {1+y^{'2}}dx + \lambda \pi y^2 -\pi\int y ^2 dx \tag 1 $$

The second term

$$ 2 \lambda \pi \int y dy = 2 \lambda \pi \int y y' dx \tag 2 $$

The third term is modified with an arbitrary constant $2H $ of reciprocal linear dimension turning volume term also to second degree.

Dividing by $2 \pi$ the Lagrangian takes the form

$$ y\left( \sqrt {1+y^{'2}} + \lambda y' - H y \right) =F \tag 3$$

From Euler Lagrange Equation Beltrami pde integration without explicit $x$ term

$$ F -y'~\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} = c $$

$$ y ~ ( \sqrt {1+y^{'2}} + \lambda ~y' - Hy )- y'\cdot y \left( \frac{y'}{\sqrt {1+y^{'2}}} +0 \right)=c \tag 4 $$

$$ \frac{ y}{ \sqrt {1+y^{'2} }}+ y^2 H = c \tag 5 $$

The quantity with radical sign is $ \sec \phi $; simplifying,

$$ \cos \phi = H y +\frac {c}{y} ~~ \tag 6$$

Differentiate w.r.t meridional arc $s$

$$ -\sin \phi \frac{d \phi}{ds} = ( H-\frac{c}{y^2})\sin \phi\tag 7$$

Simplifying and introducing principal curvatures with proper sign convention

$$ \kappa_2=\frac{\cos \phi}{y}; ~ \kappa1=\frac{d \phi}{ds}; \tag 8$$

$$ \frac{\kappa_1+\kappa_2 }{2}= H \tag 9 $$

This results in CMC *constant mean curvature DeLaunay* surface as a solution surface of revolution.

A sphere is a particularly simple case, $c=0$.

As is known, a CMC surface  encloses maximum volume for given surface area.

Among three CMC surface of revolution varieties is the following unduloid of wavy /corrugated shape. Two other toroidal types are not likely to be really usable as a coffee cup... although a workaround might still be possible.

EDIT1:

Did not take the calculation to its full logical conclusion including drinking rate/time etc.( reg. physics of formulation). For large number of unduloid waves an asymptotic value of $ Vol^{1/3}/Area^{1/2} \approx 0.44 $ seems attained that is less than OP's value  0.56;

[image]

Comment: What are you actually claiming as the optimal shape here? It is not clear from this answer, and the images you display are non-convex, which I believe is provably suboptimal.

Comment: Hi  @RavenclawPrefect, I 've edited as above.

Comment: Your answer still does not clearly specify what you claim to be the optimal shape, and your final image is *still* of a non-convex solution. I do not think this answer is correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-mean-curvature_surface has some details like unduloids, nodoids. They are expressible in terms of elliptic integrals. Depending on constants  in above ode (6) several meridians can be obtained. Should solution shapes be convex? I have computed several profiles of intersecting toroidal meridians. Also shapes defined by John Sullivan etal. 
 https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0102183

Comment: Narasimham, I have actually been working on this along similar lines but I think @RavenclawPrefect is right. Can you give an example profile with average surface area and volume. For instance the example surface provided in the question, $r(z)=\sqrt\frac{3}{2}r^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{9}r^\frac{3}{2}$,  has a starting volume of $\frac{3^4}{2^5}\pi$ and a mean surface area of 12.723452. Do any of you solution profiles do better?

Comment: Why do you think so? I do not understand average/mean surface area, but total area. You meant $r(z)=\sqrt\frac{3}{2}z^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{6}}{9}z^\frac{3}{2}?$

Comment: @MichaelMcL1960: What  single parameter do you choose to compare between calculations? E.g., non-dimensional $ V/ A^{\frac32}?$

Comment: @Narasimham. Exactly (well, an exact equivalent). I have the volume fixed and minimise the average surface area.

Comment: I think what you may not be considering is that because the liquid is draining over time it is essentially a 4 dimensional object.

Comment: The goal is not to minimize $\int 2 \pi r ds + \pi r^2$. The goal is to minimize the surface area times the time spent drinking, which is given by the formula in the OP.

Comment: Show us the money! What is the equation of r(z) ? Note that 0.5596 is the ratio using the starting volume and the average surface area. Obviously the average volume will be half of the original volume for a constant drinking rate.

Comment: The ODE after first integration is $ \cos \phi= r-\frac{H}{r},~ \tan \phi = \frac{dr}{dz}$. Integrating,  this unduloid is obtained. Can be further integrated with elliptic integrals I guess may be searched from DeLaunay's references. I sort of gave up on this after a day's work. Btw, Blashke's DG book says that the locus of focus of any conic traces out  (while rolling without slip on a straight line ) the meridian of such pressurized soap bubbles.

Comment: The coffee cup cooling process has three components, heat flow via walls by temperature difference to environment, heat radiation to the radiation field at environment temperature over the open surface. But the most important is evaporation against humidity at room temperature. So bottle shapes are a must.